# gravatar won't get my image

Tags: laravel-5, gravatar

i am using this package<

```
thomaswelton/laravel-gravatar
```

yes its working good when i use this code

```
<img src="{{ Gravatar::src('imsidzluv@gmail.com') }}" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```

but its a static image so i trying to change this to dynamic like this

```
<img src="{{ Gravatar::src('{!! Auth::user()->email !!}') }}" class="img-circle img-responsive">
and 
<img src="{!! Gravatar::src('{{ Auth::user()->email }}') !!}" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```

this won't work why any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it's not being loaded is actually you are passing the whole `{!! Auth::user()->email !!}` argument as a string so that it's not being printed as you may think for the static Gravatar `src` function.

Just pass it like below.

```
<img src="{{ Gravatar::src(Auth::user()->email) }}" class="img-circle img-responsive">
```